# What if I edit out information/code that resulted in an upvote?

Tags: discussion, support

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26941864/how-to-find-out-if-tomcat-has-stopped-running-with-batch/26943732#26943732) the OP asks how to delay execution of a command until a program has stopped running. I misunderstood the question at first and provided code that would test either case--had program started running, had it stopped running.

The original question wasn't expressed very clearly, so I decided to edit it. That's when I realized OP didn't care about whether the program had started running, just whether or not it had stopped, so off I go to edit my answer to include only the one case.

As soon as I'm done I see that my rep had increased by 10. Now I'm concerned that the question and answer upvotes were based on the 2-case scenario which I edited out. It *was* a thorough and generally helpful solution, but it was more than the OP asked for or needed. Is there something one should do in a case like this--beyond reading more closely next time and not worrying about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say your answer does "more" than what the question asked. If the "more" part is closely related to the problem in the question, then leave it. I sometimes provide an answer that does more than what the question asked, strictly speaking. There's no harm in this so long as what is provided is closely related to the question.

If the "more" part is not actually related to the problem in the question, then this part should go. You should not worry about the upvote.

Answer (score 2):

As @Louis said, you should not worry about the *upvote*. Why? Because when you edit a post, the person who upvoted has the capability to *undo that vote*. So, that scenario has been considered.

Furthermore, if the *upvote* was made in a previous revision of your answer, you can easily *rollback* to that revision and continue making edits if you like without losing the upvote.

Comment: Didn't know about rollback. Excellent!